# Database connection fails when connecting using sqlcmd with encrypt connection

Tags: sql-server, ssl, encryption, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlcmd

I am trying to connect to sql server with forced encryption using sqlcmd.

I have added a certificate to sql server and enabled forced encryption.

But the sqlcmd tool is not able to connect to the sql server. Below is the command I am using:

```
sqlcmd -S"mymachine.mydomain.dom" -b -d"mydatabase" -i"E:\mysqlfile.sql" 
-v mode="Load"  -N -U"sa" -P"password"
```

this works when I remove mydomain.dom and -N option like:

```
sqlcmd -S"mymachine" -b -d"mydatabase" -i"E:\mysqlfile.sql" 
-v mode="Load" -U"sa" -P"password"
```

What may be the reason?

Edit : I have stored the server certificate in both personal and trusted people store. I also ran the follwing query to check the encryption .

```
SELECT encrypt_option FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
```

encrypt_option is true for all the sessins.

Edit 2 : I am using a default instance. The certificate CN is mymachine.mydomain.dom. Also another connection to the same database with encrypt=true and using .net code is working fine. So this doesn't seems to be a certificate issue.

Edit 3 : Tcp/ip is enabled in network configuration. Remote connection is also enabled. I also tried executing sqlcmd as administrator but got the same error.

Comment: Is there a chance `sqlcmd` shows some kind of an error message?

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired.

Comment: could you please confirm that you have the alias set up for the architecture your `sqlcmd` is built for? Configuration Manager / Native Client (32 or 64 bit) / Aliases